# Send email using php from outlook (com component) ,using particular account

Tags: php, outlook

I am using PHP and outlook to send email.
I have multiple accounts set up in outlook, and I want to send email from a particular account each time.
My current code looks like:

```
if (!defined('olMailItem')) define("olMailItem",0);
$objApp = new COM("Outlook.Application");
$myItem = $objApp->CreateItem(olMailItem);
$myItem->To= 'to@abc.com';
$myItem->SentOnBehalfOfName = 'from@xyz.com';
$myItem->Subject='my subject';

$myItem->HTMLBody='email content';
$myItem->Display();
$myItem->Send()
```

using `$myItem->SentOnBehalfOfName` doesn't works, it always sends email using default account, but I want to set the from account using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are interested in the [SendUsingAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869311.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of the MailItem class which allows to set an Account object that represents the account under which the MailItem is to be sent. The SendUsingAccount property can be used to specify the account that should be used to send the MailItem when the Send method is called. For example:

```
Sub SendUsingAccount() 
  Dim oAccount As Outlook.account 
  For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts 
    If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then 
      Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
      Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
      oMail.Subject = "Sent using POP3 Account" 
      oMail.Recipients.Add ("someone@example.com") 
      oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll 
      oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount 
      oMail.Send 
    End If 
  Next 
End Sub
```

Be aware, Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Can you please explain usage of `oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount` , specially what does `oAccount` means here

Comment: It is an instance of the Account class. Take a look at the Accounts property of the Namespace class for more information about all configured accounts in the Outlook profile.

Comment: Thanks again.The problem I am getting is as follows:
when I use `oMail.SendUsingAccount = "abc@xyz.com"`, it doesn't works.
Is there any way to get oAccount object using account email id like:
`oAccount = new oAccount("abc@xyz.com")`.

Comment: No, you need to find the corresponding Account object in the Accounts collection (see the Accounts property of the Namespace class).

Comment: Do I need to loop all accounts each time to find matching account object , to send email ?

Comment: You can find it once.